# Copy an object in universal Windows Application (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

In want to add a copy of an object to a List in a universal Windows Application. I tried several ways and found IClonable,BinaryFormatter,IFormatter which are all not available in WinRT applications. Please advice me a suitable way to copy a object to a new object. Find my code below.

```
foreach (var ctrls in _listctrldata)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < ctrls.Controls.Control.Count; )
     {
        listofcontrolvalues.Add(ctrls.Controls.Control[index]);
        index++;
     }

   SetControlvalues(null, _vcontainer, listofcontrolvalues);

 //_vcontainer changes everytime the loop rotates and Should create a copy of  _vcontainer here//  

  VerticalContainer vcont = new VerticalContainer ();
  vcont = _vcontainer;

 _listcontrols.Add(vcont);

}
```

Comment: Don't copy objects, it's not a good idea and it's not consistent with how C# should be written. Maybe create a _vcontainer every time. Maybe create a new object from the data in _vcontainer to add to your list. Don't copy.

Comment: The problem I am facing is even after creating new instance for each loop rotation finally I am getting the same value in the list(i.e all values changes to the last added values to the list). please see my updated code.

Comment: The line `VerticalContainer vcont = new VerticalContainer ();` is pointless, because you assign `vcont = _vcontainer;` The variable `vcont`  now points at the same object as `_vcontainer`. I'm would read up on how [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) work.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what the class VerticalContainer is.

If it is a .NET class defined by you self, you can just defined a clone method to create a new object and copy all of the build-in data type fields.
If it is a Windows Runtime class, I’m afraid you cannot easily copy it because there are some internal and private data members you cannot access.

In your code.
VerticalContainer vcont = new VerticalContainer ();  vcont = _vcontainer;

You only changed the vcont reference from new created object to the old _vcontainer, this will not work, you need to copy all of fields from _vcontainer to vcont one by one.